# (Linear algebra) if $A$ is normal matrix then, eigenvectors of $ A$ are orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that the eigenvectors of a unitary matrix are orthogonal. Then is that also true for a normal matrix? How do I prove?

Comment: Not all eigenvectors are orthogonal. Ever. (Well, unless there aren't any...) What you mean here is whether there exists an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: You can prove that eigenvectors relative to *different* eigenvalues are orthogonal. Counterexample: every nonzero vector is an eigenvector for the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2):

The *spectral theorem* states that a matrix $A$ is normal if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable by a unitary matrix $U$, i.e. $A = U D U^\dagger$ for a diagonal matrix $A$.

It is easy to see that, for every unitarily diagonalizable matrix, we can choose a basis of orthogonal eigenvectors:
The columns of $U$ are eigenvectors of $A$, and $U$ is by definition unitary if and only if its columns are orthogonal (with respect to the inner product of $\mathbb C^n$).

Comment: Is that the columns of U are eigenvectors of A in this case? I don't know why it is.

Comment: "The" eigenvectors of a scalar matrix, which is diagonal, can very well not be orthogonal. Also you certainly did not mean to say, as you did, that the eigenvectors of _every diagonalizable_ matrix are orthogonal. You want to stay with normal matrices here.

Comment: @Roland: That's always the case. (Note though that I just edited a typo, it needs to be $A = UDU^\dagger$, not $U^\dagger D U$.)

To understand it, maybe think about it this way: $U^\dagger A U$ needs to do the same thing like $D$. For this, $U$ needs to map a unit vector $e_i$ to the i-th eigenvector of $A$. Then $A$ just multiplies this eigenvector with its eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ and $U^\dagger$ maps this back to $\lambda_i e_i$. Which is equal to $D e_i$.

You see that, if the columns of $U$ are the eigenvectors of $A$, then $A = UDU^\dagger$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You are right, I wasn't precise. I should have said: For a diagonalizable matrix, we can choose an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. If an eigenspace has dimension greater than one, there are eigenvectors which are not orthogonal.

Comment: @Noiralef: No you should not have said that. For a diagonalizable matrix one can find an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors **if and only if the matrix is normal**. Most matrices with distinct eigenvalues will leave you no choice but to choose non-orthogonal eigenvectors in a basis.

Comment: Not all diagonalizable matrices have orthogonal eigenvectors, try $\pmatrix{1&2\\3&4}$. Nevertheless, I believe that this answer assumes what the question asks for.

Comment: Right, sorry. I was thinking about unitarily diagonalizable, but not writing it... I edited my answer, now it should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices) that states what you ask. But since you asked for a proof, here is one.

The matrix defines a normal operator$~T$ on a complex inner product space$~V$, and I will prove, by induction on the dimension, that such operators admit an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors. (The operator point of view is more flexible than the matrix point of view, and abstracts away from the standard basis of $\Bbb C^n$, which although orthonormal has no specific relation to the problem at hand.)

If the dimension of the space is zero, the basis is empty and we are done. Otherwise, like any linear operator on a finite non-zero dimensional complex vector space, our $T$ has as least one eigenvalue; choose one and call it$~\lambda$. Since $T$ is normal, the eigenspaces of $T$ are $T^*$-stable, so we can restrict $T^*$ to the eigenspace $E_\lambda$ of$~T$ for$~\lambda$, and find an eigenvector $v\in E_\lambda$ that is also an eigenvector for $T^*$. The later maens that $\langle v\rangle$ is nonzero and $T^*$-stable which by simple algebra implies that $\langle v\rangle^\perp$ is $T$-stable. Since we are in an inner product space, $V=\langle v\rangle\oplus\langle v\rangle^\perp$. By restriction $T$ defines a normal operator on the complex inner product space $\langle v\rangle^\perp$ which has dimension one less than$~V$. We can apply induction to get an orthogonal basis of $\langle v\rangle^\perp$ consisting of eigenvectors of (the restriction and therefore of) $T$. Together with $v$, one has an orthogonal basis of$~V$ consisting  of eigenvectors of$~T$.